# is there pytorch's max operation in tensorflow2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

```
overlap-> tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,  ..., 0.6466, 0.7945, 0.5389]],
       device='cuda:0')

overlap_for_each_prior, object_for_each_prior = overlap.max(dim=0)  # (8732)
```

this .max(dim=0) return the two returns.
is there any equivalence method in tensorflow 2.0?

Comment: I think this would better asked on Stack Overflow. Although these are both Python libraries that can be used in the context of AI, the question is not about AI, but about a feature of the software libraries. In general this site focuses on maths and theory of AI, not technical features of the tools.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to use [`tf.math.argmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/argmax). Using it, you can get maximum element(s) as well:

```
A = tf.constant([2, 20, 30, 3, 6])
maximum_index = tf.math.argmax(A)
A[maximum_index], maximum_index
# >>> 30, 2
```